# How to free port 80 for xampp to work

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost, xampp

Please help,
I used to be running xampp and it was working perfectly.
Then I wanted to try something out and I ran IIS instead of xampp.
Now I want to go back to using xampp, but whenever I try to run the apache server it says:
Busy...
Apache started [port 80]
If I go to http://localhost/ then it just says that it can't establish a connection to the server. I have turned off IIS, so I don't see why it shouldn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try turning off the DNS client service..

Comment: More appropiate for serverfault.com ... But, did you try to run IISRESET /STOP to make sure all IIS related services has stopped ? Otherwise, try pointing your browser to http://localhost, and see if is a page served by IIS or something else.

Comment: Kill or stop IIS, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Run netstat -ab as administrator, and you get a list of processes which are listening to port 80. This way you can find out which process is bound to that port.

But this list can be quite big, so the easiest is to echo it to a file

`netstat -ab > netstat.txt`

Then you can try to search in that file for port 80.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind guys, I've decided I'm just going to use IIS instead. Thanks anyway though

Comment: Close this question, please then.